# Postgres update query complaining about text value when only NULL values are passed

Tags: postgresql, update, postgresql-9.4

I am using Postgres 9.4.6.

Is there any reason why the below update query would execute successfully here:-

```
UPDATE "Predictions" 
    SET "userid" = c."userid",
        "Fixture_No" = c."Fixture_No",
        "Home_Side_Score" = c."Home_Side_Score",
        "Away_Side_Score" = c."Away_Side_Score"
    FROM (VALUES(288, 1, NULL, NULL),(288, 34, 1, 1))
    AS c("userid", "Fixture_No", "Home_Side_Score", "Away_Side_Score")
    WHERE "Predictions"."Fixture_No" = c."Fixture_No" AND "Predictions"."userid" = c."userid"
```

But with these values, the same query would fail with "ERROR:  column "Home_Side_Score" is of type smallint but expression is of type text
LINE 4:    "Home_Side_Score" = c."Home_Side_Score",":

```
UPDATE "Predictions" 
    SET "userid" = c."userid",
        "Fixture_No" = c."Fixture_No",
        "Home_Side_Score" = c."Home_Side_Score",
        "Away_Side_Score" = c."Away_Side_Score"
    FROM (VALUES(288, 1, NULL, NULL),(288, 34, NULL, NULL))
    AS c("userid", "Fixture_No", "Home_Side_Score", "Away_Side_Score")
    WHERE "Predictions"."Fixture_No" = c."Fixture_No" AND "Predictions"."userid" = c."userid"
```

This doesn't make any sense as I am not trying to pass postgres text instead of an integer?

My predictions table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "Predictions"
(
  userid smallint,
  "Fixture_No" smallint,
  "Home_Side_Score" smallint,
  "Away_Side_Score" smallint,
  "Prediction_ID" bigserial NOT NULL,
  "Joker_Played" boolean,
  "Result" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 4,
  CONSTRAINT "Predictions_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Prediction_ID"),
  CONSTRAINT "Result_Type" FOREIGN KEY ("Result")
      REFERENCES "ResultTypes" ("Result_ID") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE "Predictions"
  OWNER TO bjlizgykrnyffr;
```

Comment: You probably need to cast the values of the first group: `VALUES (288, 1, NULL::smallint, NULL::smallint), ...`

Comment: What @ypercubeᵀᴹ says - no idea where the `text` is inferred from, in similar cases I'd expect `unknown` in its place.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ But I don't understand why, in example one, it iterates through one set of NULL values but still executes successfully.

Comment: @LemusThelroy I think it does not iterate in the strict sense of the word.  From the second record it can infer which type the `NULL`s are.

Comment: @dezso what can I change in the code to overcome this issue and allow me to pass two sets of null values if I wanted to?

Comment: @LemusThelroy cast them, like written above.